# Rerender only occurs on second state change,

Tags: reactjs

I am hoping you guys can help me,
I think I may be missing a simple concept. I have a Component within that there is another component that has an array that is prop drilled from its parent component. In the Child component, the list is then mapped and displayed.

Now the issue is when I update the state of the Array, ie add another item to the Array using SetArray([...array, newItem]),

the useEffect in the ChildComponent will console.log the new array but the actual display does not change until I add another element to the array.

When I add another element the first element I added appears but the 2nd one doesn't.

Hopefully, that makes some sense

ChildComponent:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
////EDITOR//// List

import { Grid, Button, Card } from "@material-ui/core";
import Timestamp from "./Timestamp";

const TimestampList = ({ setTime, match, setMatchEdit, render }) => {
  const [timestamps, setTimestamps] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const setInit = async () => {
      try {
        console.log(match);
        const m = await match.scores.map(player => {
          console.log(player);
          if (player.totalScores) {
            return player.totalScores;
          }
        });
        console.log(m);
        if (m[0] && m[1]) {
          setTimestamps(
            [...m[0], ...m[1]].sort((a, b) => {
              return a.time - b.time;
            })
          );
        }

        if (m[0] && !m[1]) {
          setTimestamps(
            m[0].sort((a, b) => {
              return a.time - b.time;
            })
          );
        }

        if (m[1] && !m[0]) {
          setTimestamps(
            m[1].sort((a, b) => {
              return a.time - b.time;
            })
          );
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    if (match) {
      setInit();
    }
    console.log(match);
  }, [match]);

  return (
    <Grid
      component={Card}
      style={{ width: "100%", maxHeight: "360px", overflow: "scroll" }}
    >
      {timestamps && timestamps.map(timestamp => {
        console.log(timestamp);
        const min = Math.floor(timestamp.time / 60);
        const sec = timestamp.time - min * 60;
        const times = `${min}m ${sec}sec`;
        return (
          <Timestamp
          
            time={times}
            pointsScored={timestamp.points}
          
          />
        );
      })}
      <Grid container direction='row'></Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default TimestampList;
```

Comment: If you can provide code that would help.

Comment: Create a new array and use ```setState``` to replace it.

Comment: I tried create a new array and replacing it, had no luck